# MySQL - need to select negative values as positive

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL tables: `subscriptions` and `groups.`
Column `sid` in table `subscriptions` contains negative values but column `id` in table `groups` contain the same values but positive.

I need some method to convert `sid` values to positive values before joining table `groups`, or a query that will treat all values in table `id` as negative values

Below is my query. It doesn't return any results because column `sid` contains negative values, but column `id` contains positive values

```
$tmp = mysqli_query($con1,"
SELECT s.uid 
     , s.sid
     , g.title 
  FROM subscriptions s 
  LEFT
  JOIN groups g 
    ON s.sid = g.id  
 WHERE s.uid = $id 
 LIMIT 0,20
") or die('Error8');
```

Comment: How about `g.id = -s.sid` ?

Comment: It's great that you're using a modern API (mysqli), but part of the beauty of that API is that it allows the use of prepared statements!

Comment: Prepared statements are for sissies :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ABS` function will do what you need:

> Returns the absolute value of X.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs